# Comparing two synonyms using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to compare between different documents. How can I overcome conflicts while representing synonyms, this example would give different vectors. while they have the same meaning.

```
text1, text2= "I like birds", "I admire birds"
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
```

Note: I found that some papers referring to `Latent Semantic analysis`, does NLTK support that ?

Answer (score 1):

LSA is a nice way to get around the synonym problem, however NLTK does not implement that. It should be straightforward to implement if you have the research papers, though.

Another way to do this would be to leverage WordNet. From their introduction (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/):

> WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept.

NLTK has already helpfully implemented this for you (http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html). I'll leave the exact implementation details to you. Good luck!